# ios background images sizes and naming in xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, human-interface

I am using xamarin.forms to develop an app. The app has screens with background images. So to have proper background's i referred to the ios documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) with taking dimensions of the launch/splash screen into consideration as they are like background images, but this doesn't work. This is what i follow:

iPhone

- 320 x 480    Default.png
- 640 x 960    Default@2x.png
- 640 x 1136   Default-568h@2x.png
- 750 x 1334   Default-667h@2x.png
- 1242 x 2208  Default-736h@3x.png
- 2208 x 1242  Default-Landscape@3x.png

iPad

- 768 x 1024   Default-Portrait.png
- 1536 x 2048  Default-Portrait@2x.png
- 1024 x 768   Default-Landscape.png
- 2048 x 1536  Default-Landscape@2x.png

the images in iphone 6 (iOS 9.0) are repeating.

**EDIT:**
I needed the naming convention and sizes for the image to be used as background images in xamarin.forms content page.

Any help on this sizes and naming?

Comment: Better:
1536 x 2008 Default-Portrait@2x.png, and 
2048 x 1496 Default-Landscape@2x.png

Answer (score 3):

I have also been struggling with this, it seems like the iPhone 6 (Plus) screens aren't implemented in Xamarin.Forms.

**LaunchScreen**

This is probably because [Apple themselves](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1) are recommending the use of Storyboards and/or XIB files for your LaunchScreen as of iPhone 6, or better yet iOS 8.

I quote:

> In iOS 8 and later, you can create a XIB or storyboard file instead of
>   a static launch image. When you create a launch file in Interface
>   Builder, you use size classes to define different layouts for
>   different display environments and you use Auto Layout to make minor
>   adjustments. Using size classes and Auto Layout means that you can
>   create a single launch file that looks good on all devices and display
>   environments.

This, in fact, *is* supported by Xamarin.Forms.

Just create a StoryBoard in your Resources file, configure your splash screen and select it as LaunchScreen in your `info.plist` file.

[image: info.plist editor in Xamarin Studio]

Advantage is that it works for all devices.

**Background images**

As for background images, according to the [Xamarin iOS documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/sizes-and-filenames/) this *should* work.
If it doesn't for Xamarin.Forms you should probably report a bug.
Meanwhile you could use a custom renderer like underneath, taken from the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27327/ios-background-image-scale) or check another suggestion from that thread:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(InfoPage), typeof(InfoPage_iOS))]

namespace Oxaco_BBC.iOS
{
    public class InfoPage_iOS : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(false);

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(this.View.Frame.Size);
            UIImage i = UIImage.FromFile("Background.png");
            i = i.Scale(this.View.Frame.Size);

            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(i);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Life saver! In my case I needed to get the background from the bundle

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=windows#adding-images-to-an-asset-catalog-image-set